# UDataTable.FindRow always returns null

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I'm new to Unreal coming from Unity and I'm trying to use a UDataTable to store and edit some data, but every time I try to find a row in the table, it returns null with this error message.This is UE5.3

[LogDataTable: Error: UDataTable::FindRow : 'Roll Counts' specified no row for DataTable '/Engine/Transient.DataTable_0'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPJSS.png)

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "RollTracker", meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
class UDataTable* rollDataTable;
```

```
void AMainGameMode::AddRoll(int roll) 
{
    rolls.push_back(roll);

    if (rollDataTable == NULL) 
    {
        rollDataTable = NewObject<UDataTable>();
        // I've already checked and made sure that this only ever happens once
    }

    static const FString ContextString(TEXT("Roll Counts"));
    FName rowName = FName(FString::FromInt(roll));
    FRollData* row = rollDataTable->FindRow<FRollData>(rowName, ContextString, true);

    if (!row) 
    {
        row = new FRollData();
        row->roll = roll;
        row->count = 1;
        rollDataTable->AddRow(rowName, *row);
    }
    else 
    {
        row->count++;
        //This else block never happens because row is always null even when it shouldnt be
    }                                                                                                   
}
```

Basically I'm keeping count of dice being rolled. So if AddRoll() was called like so

```
AddRoll(1);
AddRoll(2);
AddRoll(1);
AddRoll(3);
```

The expected result would be a data table with 3 Rows
Row 1: 2
Row 2: 1
Row 3: 1

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you set `rollDataTable` to `nullptr` somewhere before calling `AddRoll`? Are you, thus, sure `if (rollDataTable == NULL)` is entered at all? If not, `rollDataTable` will continue to point to some random location with no valid object (as it did since initialization).

Comment: Note that in C++ initialization without an initializer is called [default-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) and it leaves pointers (and other built-in types) non-initialized (i.e. with an indeterminate value).

Comment: Also, in `row = new FRollData();` you leak memory because you never `delete` the newly created object and `UDataTable::AddRow` [copies](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UDataTable/AddRow/) the data from second argument, not takes ownership of it. There's no need for dynamic memory management here, you can make a local `FRollData` variable and it will have automatic storage duration (which practically speaking usually means it will be 'on the stack').

Comment: This feels like an xy-problem. [DataTables](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/data-driven-gameplay-elements-in-unreal-engine/) are assets that you populate in the editor to read from. They are not data bases. If you want to store data, use another data type. Also using "push_back" implies you are using std::vector. You should use [TArray](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/TArrays/) for that in unreal.

Answer (score 1):

`UDataTable` is a **static** data type. It's used to populate data in the editor that will not be mutated during runtime.
Edit: *Technically* it can be, but it's not the intended use case.

Some examples what it could typically be used for:

- Inventory items in your game. (Although not the best way to do this, check out Lyra and use `DataAssets`)
- Loot Tables
  Basically anything you want to look up using an `FName` to get some static data.

What you are making seems to be a runtime record of some rolls that have happened.

Here's another way of achieving what you are trying to do:

```
// A Map of dice roll to number of times the dice roll has happened.
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Transient, Category = "RollTracker", meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
TMap<int32, int32> Rolls;
```

Please note that I've added `Transient` to the UPROPERTY specifiers, as that implies that this data is transient/temporary/non-persisted. This means it will never save the data inside of this Rolls `TMap` to disk inside of the uasset or instance of the actor/actorcomponent placed into a Level. You use this whenever you have data that only really needs to be created and stay alive during runtime.
I've also removed the `EditAnywhere`, as a system like this wouldn't really make sense to be accessible in editor. Keeping the `BlueprintReadOnly` so you can read the state if you want from blueprint.

```
void AMainGameMode::AddRoll(int32 NumberRoll) 
{
    // Finding or adding the rolled number, and incrementing it to keep count.
    // This system now technically supports any sided dice.
    Rolls.FindOrAdd(NumberRoll)++;                                                                                            
}

int32 AMainGameMode::GetRollCount(int32 NumberRoll) const
{
    if(int32* FoundRoll = Rolls.Find(NumberRoll))
    {
        return *FoundRoll;
    }

    // If we can't find it, it hasn't been rolled yet.
    return 0;
}
```

Finally I would like to add a word of advice based on my own experience:
Do not use `UDataTable` for anything that you would want to keep track of the references. If you ever think you'll have to go and change the name of a Row in a DataTable, be aware that everywhere in your game or your saved data that has a referenece to that Row is just an FName. They will not be automatically updated in any way to know that you changed that Row name.
If you have this situation, look into using DataAssets and the AssetManager.